# c++ socket stream api

Tags: c++, api, class, sockets, stream

I'm using what looks to be a real nice API for streaming sockets found here:
http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~dgame/sockets/socketsC++/sockets.html.

I'm having trouble accessing the IP of the connected user because its a private member of a class "Socket" that is used within another class "ServerSocket". My program looks exactly like the demo only it it forks processes.

```
// libraries
#include <signal.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// headers
#include "serversocket.hpp"
#include "socketexception.hpp"
#include "config.hpp"

using namespace std;

void sessionHandler( ServerSocket );


int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    configClass config; // this object handles command line args
    config.init( argc, argv ); // initialize config with args

    pid_t childpid; // this will hold the child pid

    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); // this prevents zombie processes on *nix

    try
    {
        ServerSocket server ( config.port ); // create the socket

        cout << "server alive" << "\n";
        cout << "listening on port: " << config.port << "\n";

        while ( true )
        {

            ServerSocket new_client; // create socket stream
            server.accept ( new_client ); // accept a connection to the server

            switch ( childpid = fork() ) // fork the child process
            {
            case -1://error
                cerr << "error spawning child" << "\n";
                break;
            case 0://in the child
                sessionHandler( new_client ); // handle the new client
                exit(0); // session ended normally
                break;
            default://in the server
                cout << "child process spawned: " << childpid << "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( SocketException& e ) // catch problem creating server socket
    {
        cerr << "error: " << e.description() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}


// function declarations

void sessionHandler( ServerSocket client )
{
    try
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            string data;
            client >> data;
            client << data;
        }
    }
    catch ( SocketException& e )
    {
        cerr << "error: " << e.description() << "\n";
    }
}
```

So my question is, can I not access the IP of the client currently connected to the socket? If it has to be modified for that functionality, what would the cleanest way to do it be?

### Thanks for suggestions

I was able to add these 2 functions that allowed me to get the IP only from the scope of main like this:

server.get_ip( new_client );
but what I'd really like is to get it like this new_client.ip();

here's my 2 functions, maybe you can help me further:

```
std::string Socket::get_ip( Socket& new_socket )
{
  char cstr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
  std::string str;
  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(m_addr.sin_addr), cstr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  str = cstr;
  return str;
}

std::string ServerSocket::get_ip( ServerSocket& sock )
{
    return Socket::get_ip( sock );
}
```

Comment: From a performance standpoint, you should not fork() a new process for each client. That has a lot of overhead. You may wish to consider Boost.Asio since it can handle event-driven communication automatically, but it is a steep learning curve for the uninitiated.

Comment: consider making your new functions `const`, so that they look like: `std::string Socket::get_ip(Socket& new_socket) const { ... }` and `std::string ServerSocket::get_ip(ServerSocket& sock) const { ... }`, since they should not modify the `Socket`.

Comment: thank you I will look in to learning Asio, and also thanks for the const suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Socket class you are using has a private data member:

```
sockaddr_in m_addr;
```

This contains the info of the client connected to the socket. You can get the human-readable address with:

```
char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(m_addr.sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

As for the changes you need to make, either make `m_addr` public (not recommended) or add a member function that can return a string based on the above code sample.

Comment: thanks I got a little further, and put more details in my question and what I've done so far